# Creating Form element ids in the form template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Im new to Django and I am trying to create a form that contains a table of drop downs. This is for generating a script based on user selections in these drop downs when submit is clicked.

The problem is the following form template is creating duplicate form element ids

> > How do I create unique ids in the form template even though the drop downs are going to be repeated.

The following is the code of the drop down.

```
<html>
<table border="1">
  <form action="/PrintTestScript/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <tr>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Endpoint</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Box Type</th>
  </tr>
  {% for i in 0123456789|make_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>
       {{form.action}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{form.series}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{form.epstatus}}
    </td>
    <td>
       {{form.boxtype}}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
  </tr>
 </form>
 </table>
 </html>
```

The following is the form class definition.

```
  class TestForm(ModelForm):
      action = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=actions.objects.all(), empty_label="")
      series = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=endpoints.objects.all(), empty_label="")
      epstatus = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=status.objects.all(), empty_label="")
      boxtype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=boxtype.objects.all())

      class Meta:
          model = endpoints
          exclude = ('end_point_alias', 'dial_num', 'ip_address')
```

This is where the view is getting created

```
def getvals(request):
      form = TestForm()

      return render_to_response('main.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `<form>` tag within the `for` loop, so that you are actually creating 10 different forms instead of 10 copies of the same form elements. But you still have the problem that you would need 10 separate submit buttons. If you're actually looking for a list of forms, check out the Django `FormSet` [documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Thanks for the input on FormSet. I was reluctant to go into formset.. but now I see that it is very powerful. Thanks for your inputs.